Setting preconditions in Stellar Laboratory?
The documentation describes a way to set up interesting preconditions on transactions, yet there's seemingly no way to utilize them in Stellar Laboratory that only lets us enter Time Bounds, but not things like Minimum sequence number. Is there a tool that allows building such transactions?
